# Joomla K2 change pagination titles by adding number of the page to the pagination

Tags: joomla, pagination, joomla-k2

Can you tell me how can I add custom title to the pagination title in K2
On all pages (1,2,3 etc.) the title is the same, and I want to add Page1, Page2, etc., so the titles to become like this: title+Page1, title+page2, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution, so hope it will be useful for others too :)

In the file /components/com_k2/views/itemlist/view.html.php

Find Line 196:

```
// Set title
$title = $category->name;
```

and change to:

```
// Set title
$titlesuffix = ' Page #' . (intval($limitstart/$limit)+1);
$title = $category->name . $titlesuffix;
```

You can use this code for tag pagination, metadescription. Just search the needed lines in the same file

Answer (score 0):

Until this is sorted permanently by being part of the code (as it makes sense), here's a cleaner solution that does not require changing core K2 code: https://github.com/getk2/k2/issues/539

Comment: This is a "link-only answer". This means that your contribution is low-quality and prone to breakage if the destination page dies or is moved.  While reference links can help researchers to find the source of your advice, it is imperative that your advice is expressed in a static fashion.  This is true on all Stack Exchange sites.  Please [edit] your post.  If left as is, moderators may choose to convert this answer to a comment under the question.